# Calculating column number based on Excel alpha column reference

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, algebra

Here's a super fun brain teaser!!!

Can you give me a mathematical equation to calculate the column number of a Microsoft Excel column, given the alphabetic column reference? Let X, Y, & Z represent the alphabetic sequence number, relative to the alphabet (A = 1, B = 2, etc.)

I look forward to seeing your answers... ALGEBRAIC!

Comment: Isn't this trivial?  It's just base 26 arithmetic.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial:

> the text input is simply a $1\text{-based}$ radix $26$ representation of the number to output.

Formally

> Let [alphabet](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Alphabet) $\Delta=\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z\}$
>  the input be a [word](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Word) $\Gamma=\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\cdots,\gamma_{\ell(\Gamma)}\}|\gamma \in \Delta$
>  and $F:\Delta\mapsto[1,26]$
>  Now a function to produce our required output is:
>  \begin{align}column(\Gamma)=\sum_{p=1}^{\ell(\Gamma)}26^{\ell(\Gamma)-p}F(\gamma_p)\end{align}

I do not have Excel, so here is Python code that does the same thing:

> ```
> def ColumnNumber(text):
>     return sum(26**p*(ord(c)-64) for p, c in enumerate(text[-1::-1]))
> ```

VBA can (relevant Python code in brackets):

> reverse the text (`text[-1::-1]`),
>  loop through something (`for .. in`),
>  take powers (`26**p`),
>  find the ordinal of an ASCII character (`ord(c)`), and
>  sum numbers (`sum()`) - probably by keeping a variable and using `+`.
>
>  The `enumerate` would probably need to be done manually by keeping a variable counting the number of loops, starting at $0$, so it should be possible.

Of course we don't need to implement this anyway as we can just use the function COLUMN() with no arguments!

Comment: Not quite. AA comes after Z: that means A is 0, but 00 is the same thing as 0. (Really, it's a base-26 system with the exception that Z is a zero that adds one to the digit to the left.)

Comment: @Deusovi As I fist implemented and then realised that A is 1 not 0, since this is Excel we are talking about (AA is 27, AAA is 703) - see the code the numbers in the base are $[1,26]$ rather than $[0,25]$ due to the offset of $64$

Comment: @Deusovi I realised what you meant and clarified in the textual description

Comment: I think the mathematics is now formal

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> =column(indirect(a1 & "1"))

where a1 is the cell containing the column letter.